# Tikz pin inherited line style

Tags: tikz-pgf

Consider the following MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{memoir}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[loosely dashed] (0,0) -- (3,0)
  node[pin={[pin edge={red,<-}]below:$a$}] {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

How can I remove the dashing on the pin arrow?

Comment: With `node[pin={[pin edge={red,->}]below:$a$}] {};`. i.e. with add `solid` into pin parameters. And your image is not generated with your code, direction of pin arrow is opposite ...

Comment: @Zarko: there are sooo many `tikz` options and the index is not easy to go through. `solid` works, thanks. I've update the code to match the picture

Comment: you can add it as an answer if you want

Comment: In my country people say (literally translated) "devil is in details". I have many tima similar problems :-)

Comment: I've edited your answer, as I've already updated my original code to the direction of the arrow is correct

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The defined line style is also transferred to all elements of its command, including to the `node` and its options as `pi` is. This can be prevented with local options that overwrite line's style. In your case, to the `pin` style definition you only need to add option `solid` , i.e. node style definition should be:

```
node [pin = {[pin edge = {red, solid, <-}] below: $ a $}] {};
```

Complete MWE is:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{memoir}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[loosely dashed] (0,0) -- (3,0)
  node[pin={[pin edge={red,solid,<-}]below:$a$}] {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I have to admit I find the pin syntax particularly ugly... way too many special characters required for too little functionality.